# AWS use Bastion Host to connect to RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ssh, mysql-workbench

I have a Bastion Host with following security Group.
Inbound: Port 22 - All enabled.
Outbound: All Open.

I have a RDS with following security Group.
Inbound: 3306 Only from Bastion Host IP (Both Public & Private).
Outbound: All Open.

When I use MySQL Workbench to connect, I selected Standard TCP/IP over SSH. Provided SSH details as that of Bastion Server and MySQL host details as that of RDS.

On Test connection it says, "Can't connect to Mysql server on '127.0.0.1' (61)"

Does any one know, how to resolve this?

Comment: Try creating a tunnel with SSH. If that is working and workbench isn't, you have some issues in the workbench config.

Comment: Is this a mac?  Error `(61)` means `Connection Refused` in OSX which suggests a tunnel issue -- not something related to security groups (misconfiguration will not cause connections to be refused -- they will instead time out) and this error is not MySQL username/password related, if it helps.  @hjpotter92 is on the right track.  Troubleshoot the tunnel from the command line.

Comment: Finally I got to know why it was failing.. There were few characters after new line which where not visible. So it was incorrect IP address.. IP Address edit box should be single line field.  But yes, above mentioned approach works..